# Django + bdd + selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium, python-behave

I am using BDD features to describe some of our project. Most of scenarios are then implemented using django test client https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/, but some are being tested by selenium. In theory some of these features could be tested by both approaches (both by selenium and test client), but I don't know how to approach this from coding perspective. I want to keep my bdd scenarios implementation free (nothing like "Given I am using selenium as test tool").

I was thinking of having multiple definitions of each step when viable and then use implementation (or even more) that has all steps implemented for given scenario. That would require changing python-behave implementation I guess. Anyone facing similar issue?

Edit:

First thing I've found is to use stages and have each implementation for "stage":
https://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#test-stages
That could kinda solve my issue, I could run tests for each stage. Only thing to solve are features that are implementation(stage)-specific. Worst case scenario I can make dummy passing steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this using stages for each implementation (django, selenium) + tagging each feature and then run with corresponding stage + tag pairs.
Ex:

```
python mnage.py behave --tags=selenium --stage=selenium
```

https://pythonhosted.org/behave/new_and_noteworthy_v1.2.5.html#test-stages
https://pythonhosted.org/behave/gherkin.html#tags

Edit: this solution has one bigger downside - report contains results only from last run so if you for example use it with jenkins (as I do), you don't see all results correctly (some are set as skipped when in fact they passed earlier). But overall at least build fails when there is test error and that's main thing for me.